# Replace last 5 character from username with x

Tags: javascript, jquery, hide

I have to hide the last 5 characters of the username .
Below is the code

```
<ul>
<li>
            </dl>
                <dl>
                <dt>Username:</dt>
                <dd id="up-d-username">AZRT435231
                </dd>
            </dl>
</li>
</ul>
```

I need to replace the last 5 characters with a "X" so the output should be AZRT4XXXXX . Also is it possible that the user do not see this name from the source of the page using tools like firebug?

Comment: What if I turn off JavaScript? You need to do this with your serverside code, not your clientside code. If you send the data to your user, it's not safe.

Comment: @blender If javascript is turned off most of the applications functionality does not work , Javascript is a must . Also this is not much critical in my case , I just need to hide it. :)

Comment: I guess i can select only one answer .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it this way.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gcxuz/)**

```
txt = $.trim($('#up-d-username').text());
$('#up-d-username').text(txt.substring(0, txt.length - 5) + "XXXXX");
```

Comment: Hi Adil , I tried your approach however in the alert the txt is empty . do i need to add a delay in script execution?

Answer (score 7):

```
"AZRT435231".slice(0, -5) + "XXXXX";
```

A user may still read the original page source. If this is critical, process it with a server side language before it hits the client.

You could make a more portable version...

```
var replaceLastNChars = function(str, replace, num) {
     return str.slice(0, -num) + Array(num + 1).join(replace);
};
```

Combining it...

```
$("#up-d-username")
 .text(function(i, text) { return replaceLastNChars(text, "X", 5); });
```

Without jQuery, for fun...

```
var elem = document.getElementById("up-d-username").firstChild;

elem.data = replaceLastNChars(elem.data, "X", 5);
```

Newer browsers...

```
var elem = document.querySelector("#up-d-username");

elem.textContent = replaceLastNChars(elem.textContent, "X", 5);
```

Comment: thanx for the quick response :) I try this and let you know in sometime. Thanks again :)

Comment: I tried this but the issue is there is no value in elem ... I dont know why it is not taking the value

Comment: @Mizan Could you elaborate on that into something useful?

Answer (score 1):

You should hide this with a server-side language so that the user have no chance of seeing it with debug tools.

```
<?php
$username = "AZRT435231";
$output = substr($username, 0, -5) . "XXXXX";
?>
<ul>
<li>
            </dl>
                <dl>
                <dt>Username:</dt>
                <dd id="up-d-username"><?=$output?>
                </dd>
            </dl>
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This is the only option if security is an issue.

Comment: That would give the first 5 chars and then `"XXXXX"`. I think the OP just wants to replace the last 5.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use a regular expression, and then replace the matched string with "X" characters.

http://jsfiddle.net/uvDs8/

```
var re = /(.{1,5})$/;
var tester = "1234567890";

var new_value = tester.replace(re, function (matched) {
    return Array(matched.length+1).join("X");
});

alert(new_value);
```

In this case, it only replaces as many as possible (up to 5 at the end of the string). So, if the original value is only 4 characters long, the result is 4 "X" characters. If the result is 6 characters long, the result is the first character plus 5 "X" characters. And so on.

Answer (score 0):

The vanilla JS way to do this is:

```
 var name = document.getElementById('up-d-username');

 name.innerHTML = name.innerHTML.slice(0, -5) + "XXXXX";
```

Using jQuery, you can do it as follows:

```
var $name = $('#up-d-username');

$name.html( $name.html().slice(0, -5) + "XXXXX" );
```

There's a split second where the data is available to the browser before the replacement takes place. If someone were to simply CURL the URL, they would have access to the information. Your best bet is to replace it server side before sending it to the browser.

Comment: True, but that wasn't a part of the requirements.

Comment: I think it's implied that the function shouldn't do that.

Comment: I'm making the assumption that the individual asking the question is aware of this, which, you're correct, is a bad assumption.

Answer (score 0):

In plain JS. Also solves the issue of unknown string lengths.

```
    let mask='X'.repeat(5),
        username=document.getElementById('up-d-username');

    username=username.substring(0,username.length-mask.length)+mask;
```